# how to split a string by position in Java

Tags: java, string

I did not find anywhere an answer.. If i have: `String s = "How are you"`?
How can i split this into two strings, so first string containing from `0..s.length()/2` and the 2nd string from `s.length()/2+1..s.length()`?

Thanks!

Comment: @roddik: Given that length is an int and 2 is an int, this will do integer division, resulting in a shorter first string than second string.

Answer (score 26):

This should do:

```
String s = "How are you?";
String first = s.substring(0, s.length() / 2);  // gives "How ar"
String second = s.substring(s.length() / 2);    // gives "e you?"
```

- [`String.substring(int i)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) with one argument returns the substring beginning at position `i`
- [`String.substring(int i, int j)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) with two arguments returns the substring beginning at `i` and ending at `j-1`.

(Note that if the length of the string is odd, `second` will have one more character than `first` due to the rounding in the integer division.)

Answer (score 6):

```
String s0 = "How are you?";
String s1 = s0.subString(0, s0.length() / 2);
String s2 = s0.subString(s0.length() / 2);
```

So long as s0 is not null.

EDIT

This will work for odd length strings as you are not adding 1 to either index.  Surprisingly it even works on a zero length string "".

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'substring(start, end)', but of course check if string isn't null before:

```
String first = s.substring(0, s.length() / 2);
String second = s.substring(s.length() / 2);
```

- http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/SubstringExample.shtml

And are you expecting string with odd length ? in this case you must add logic to handle this case correctly.

Comment: But this doesn't even work... it gives `"re you"` and `"e you"`

Comment: @Torres, no, that would miss the middle character. (and throw an exception on the empty string)

Comment: Alois's answer is incorrect and Torres is also incorrect. The correct answer is `String s = "How are you?"; String first = s.substring(0, s.length() / 2); String second = s.substring(s.length() / 2);`

Comment: I give some hints, and explaining how the method work. It wasn't intended to cover perfectly the requirements, sorry. Now corrected ...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a method that splits a string into *n* items by length. (If the string length can not exactly be divided by *n*, the last item will be shorter.)

```
public static String[] splitInEqualParts(final String s, final int n){
    if(s == null){
        return null;
    }
    final int strlen = s.length();
    if(strlen < n){
        // this could be handled differently
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("String too short");
    }
    final String[] arr = new String[n];
    final int tokensize = strlen / n + (strlen % n == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        arr[i] =
            s.substring(i * tokensize,
                Math.min((i + 1) * tokensize, strlen));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

**Test code:**

```
/**
 * Didn't use Arrays.toString() because I wanted to have quotes.
 */
private static void printArray(final String[] arr){
    System.out.print("[");
    boolean first = true;
    for(final String item : arr){
        if(first) first = false;
        else System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.print("'" + item + "'");
    }
    System.out.println("]");
}

public static void main(final String[] args){

    printArray(splitInEqualParts("Hound dog", 2));
    printArray(splitInEqualParts("Love me tender", 3));
    printArray(splitInEqualParts("Jailhouse Rock", 4));

}
```

**Output:**

> ['Hound', ' dog']
>   ['Love ', 'me te', 'nder']
>   ['Jail', 'hous', 'e Ro', 'ck']

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.substring(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29), and [String.substring(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method.

```
int cutPos = s.length()/2;
String s1 = s.substring(0, cutPos);
String s2 = s.substring(cutPos, s.length()); //which is essentially the same as
//String s2 = s.substring(cutPos);
```

Comment: You've made a mistake: substring(beginPosition). so substring(cutPos) is not the same as substring(0, cutPos)

Comment: Instead of `s.substring(cutPos + 1, s.length());`, better use `s.substring(cutPos + 1);`

Comment: Sorry, this does't work either. gives `"How a"` and `"e you"` (provided you change `cutPos -` to `cutPos =`

Comment: @aioobe, thanks....the cutPos + 1 on the s2 is what caused the problem. I fixed it

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, you may want to change the first `-` into a `=` too.

Answer (score 2):

> I did not find anywhere an answer.

The first place you should always look is at the javadocs for the class in question: in this case `java.lang.String`.  The javadocs

- can be browsed online on the Oracle website (e.g. at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/),
- are included in any Sun/Oracle Java SDK distribution,
- are probably viewable in your Java IDE, and
- and be found using a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int solution(final String S, final int K) {
    int splitCount = -1;
    final int count = (int) Stream.of(S.split(" ")).filter(v -> v.length() > K).count();
    if (count > 0) {
        return splitCount;
    }

    final List<String> words = Stream.of(S.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    final List<String> subStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (final String word : words) {
        final StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
        if (subStrings.size() > 0) {
            final String oldString = subStrings.get(counter);
            if (oldString.length() + word.length() <= K - 1) {
                subStrings.set(counter, sj.add(oldString).add(word).toString());
            } else {
                counter++;
                subStrings.add(counter, sj.add(word).toString());
            }
        } else {
            subStrings.add(sj.add(word).toString());
        }
    }

    subStrings.forEach(
            v -> {
                System.out.printf("[%s] and length %d\n", v, v.length());
            }
    );
    splitCount = subStrings.size();
    return splitCount;
}
```

public static void main(final String[] args) {

```
    final MessageSolution messageSolution = new MessageSolution();
    final String message = "SMSas5 ABC DECF HIJK1566 SMS POP SUV XMXS MSMS";
    final int maxSize = 11;
    System.out.println(messageSolution.solution(message, maxSize));

}
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your code to be useful for other readers.

Comment: Split the string with specified length without a word break, the expected input contains without leading or trailing space.