# Simple way of splitting string to positions

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string with 27 characters which I would want split to two strings at the 11th char. I have researched on other questions but I don't quite understand how to go about it in simple terms if the value of the string will keep on changing. The value of the string is determined by the user input but the value will always have 26 characters, an example of the string is this

```
       String r="112345678992021-21-22T5.556"
```

How would split the string above into two strings one containing the first 11 characters and the second containing the 16 including the full stops and negative signs
Please help

Comment: Can you search the site for java substring position? Many answers already exist. If you find a good answer consider deleting the question since it seems to be a dupicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to split a string by position in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023146/how-to-split-a-string-by-position-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String first = r.substring(0,12) 
String second = r.substring(12,r.length)
```

Comment: You don't need the endIndex for second; `r.substring(12)` is sufficient.